# Can I use PHP to send a meeting invetation via exchange server?

Tags: php, email

If you use outlook then you know how you can create a meeting request and send it to different people and that shows up on their calender. I am trying to do the same idea by sending the request to a person via Php.  I am no sure if I can send the request using mail() somehow. I want the email sent and a meeting request to go on the other party's calendar.

How can I do this using php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own activesync client by sending HTTP requests according to the ActiveSync protocol:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299446(EXCHG.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee158066(v=exchg.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299441(v=exchg.80).aspx

If you look in section 2.2.2.9 of the command reference, there is mention of how to acknowledge a MeetingResponse in the user's "Inbox folder" or "Calendar folder". I would suspect that you could create an entry in the "Calendar folder" to create the initial meeting.

There's also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776088/how-to-create-an-outlook-calendar-meeting-request-in-php) on the same topic.